# Visual Studio 2015 debugging

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a serious problem with programming in Visual Basic; I want to create a program that checks if an integer is prime and I get the following code:

```
Module
    Sub Main()
        Dim a, j As Integer
        Dim prem As Boolean
        Console.Write("Veuillez entrez un entier")
        a = Console.ReadLine()
        For i = 2 To (a - 1)
            j = a Mod i
            If j = 0 Then
                prem = True ' non premier
            End If
            prem = False
        Next
        If prem = False Then
            Console.WriteLine(a & " est premier")
        Else Console.WriteLine(a & "n'est pas  premier ")
        End If
        Console.Read()
    End Sub
End Module
```

When I test, whatever the number entered, it always shows that it is prime.

And when I erase all the code to try something else, it goes back to the previous project that seems to have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get the same answer is because you continue running your code when you find `True`.

```
If j = 0 Then
    prem = True ' non premier
End If
```

That code is negated immediately by the next line `prem = False`.

If you want to stop checking when you find a true, do the following

```
If j = 0 Then
    prem = True
    Exit For
End If
```

seeing as prem will be False by default, there is no need to set it here at all. You can reduce your code to

```
For i = 2 To (a - 1)
    j = a Mod i
    If j = 0 Then prem = True
Next
```

You can then only set prem as needed. When you get out of the loop, you can know that it was never True if it is still False, and if you still need to exit when you get to true, (which i doubt after translating your comments - I'm just including this for completeness), you can do the following `If j = 0 Then prem = True : Exit For`

Answer (score 0):

AS @Fabulous pointed out once you detect your number is prime, you are setting `prem = false` in the next statement.

You also don't need to set `prem = false` in every loop because it is already false.

```
Dim a, j As Integer
Dim prem As Boolean

Console.Write("Veuillez entrez un entier")
a = Console.ReadLine()

Dim i As Integer = 2
While (i < a) AndAlso (prem = false)
    prem = (a Mod i) = 0
    i += 1
End While

If prem = False Then
    Console.WriteLine(a & " est premier")
Else 
    Console.WriteLine(a & "n'est pas  premier ")
End If

Console.Read()
```

There are also some other optimizations you can make. For example, you only need to check for factors up to Math.Sqrt(a) because if i * y = a and i > Math.Sqrt(a) the y must be < Math.Sqrt(a). Otherwise if i > Math.Sqrt(a) and y > Math.Sqrt(a) then i * y > a because Math.Sqrt(a)* Math.Sqrt(a) = a.

Another quick optimization is you don't need to check every even number, you only need to check 1a % 2 = 01 and then test odd numbers.